# How to use a float correctly with a two-column list

Tags: jquery, html, css, listitem

I am making a listing, with a two column listing, which sorts by date. I want to alternate the background color of the separate days (white/red/white/red), using this:

```
.evenDayBlock {
    background:#red
}
```

[I have created a fiddle to show the layout
http://jsfiddle.net/Ceh37/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ceh37/)

The problem is, since I have floated each list-item, the div with the class `evenDayBlock` is not extending down as the list is populated. If I remove the floats of each list-item, the div expands correctly. How do I use a float but also make sure the parent div respects the child size?

**UPDATE**

OK, I got I cannot supplant divs in with list-items as it spawns evil things. I updated the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ceh37/2/

Switched all to divs. This puts me in a little better place, as now the evenDayBlock is pushed past the first oddDayBlock, but it is still not expanding to cover all child divs it contains.

Comment: divs can't be direct children of ul's, and li's can't be direct children of divs.

Comment: I echo the comment by @KevinB. The only valid direct children of `<ul>` elements are `<li>`s, and the only valid direct parent of `<li>` elements are `<ul>`s. You may nest any elements within `<li>` or outside of `<ul>`, but no nesting should happen in between them.

Comment: @Terry  the only valid direct parent of <li> elements are <ul>s or <ol>s :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have floating elements in your block, and the background of the block does not extend to the size of it's content, you can solve this by adding "overflow:auto" to the style of the block.

```
.evenDayBlock {
    background:#red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

By the way `"#red"` seems odd to me, use `"red"` or `"#F00"`

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

After correcting the semantics of your fiddle (see comments to your question), you should try using `overflow: hidden` on the parent container of all floating elements (e.g. if `<li>`s are floated, use the overflow trick on the *direct* parent `<ul>`).

Alternatively you can use the [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) method.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you're doing it right but after you use floats and want to set a finish line you should:

```
<div style="clear:both;">
```